# Turning values into percent of the sum of all the values

Tags: ruby, hash

Lets say I have the code below. Is there any code that will turn the values into percents of the sum of all the values. For example, since the sum of all the points is 200, Harrison will be 0.4 (40%)

```
kids_points {
Harrison: 80,
Jack: 70, 
Justin: 30, 
Max: 20, 
}
```

Comment: you have to calculate it..

Comment: how do you calculate values in a hash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way :

```
kids_points = {
Harrison: 80,
Jack: 70, 
Justin: 30, 
Max: 20, 
}

def calculate_average(hash = arg.dup)
  sum_of_values = calculate_sum(hash.values)
  hash.each { |k,v| hash[k] = (100 * v) / sum_of_values }
end

def calculate_sum(enum)
  enum.reduce(:+).to_f
end

calculate_average(kids_points) 
# => {:Harrison=>40.0, :Jack=>35.0, :Justin=>15.0, :Max=>10.0}
```

Read this [`Enumerable#reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) and [`Hash#values`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-values) method.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `active_support` you can do this:

```
require 'active_support/all'

sum = hash.values.sum
hash.each { |k,v| hash[k] = (100.0 * v) / sum }
```

Note that 100.0 is necessary when percentages are not integer (most cases) or they won't sum up 100. Example:

```
hash = {
  Harrison: 60,
  Jack: 60, 
  Justin: 50, 
  Max: 50
}

# With 100.0
# => {:Harrison=>27.272727272727273, :Jack=>27.272727272727273, :Justin=>22.727272727272727, :Max=>22.727272727272727}

# With 100
# => {:Harrison=>27, :Jack=>27, :Justin=>22, :Max=>22}
```